# How to retrieve data from Ultimate Member to a field in WP Forms

Tags: wordpress, function, wpforms, ultimate-member

i want to get data from registered users in ultimate member plugin from a custom field to insert it into a hidden field in wp forms, however the meta data from ultimate member is not global as you cannot use smart tags as from default registration fields in wordpress

Anyone knows how?

I tried using the meta key from the ultimate member plugin into wp forms but it does nothing